# java/ soapfault problem in web services

Tags: java, xml, web-services, dom, jax-ws

I have the following problem:
I am using SAAJ for web services. I have a SOAPMessage with the following soap fault:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
    <S:Fault xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <faultcode>S:Server</faultcode> 
        <faultstring>java.lang.NullPointerException</faultstring> 
        <detail>
        <ns2:exception xmlns:ns2="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/" class="java.lang.NullPointerException" note="To disable this feature, set com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.disableCaptureStackTrace system property to false">
            <ns2:stackTrace>
                <ns2:frame class="myClass" file="HandlerFile.java" line="261" method="invoke" /><ns2:frame class="myClass" file="HandlerFile.java" line="1" method="invoke" /><ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1" line="unknown" method="invokeProvider" /></ns2:stackTrace>
        </ns2:exception>    
        </detail>
        </S:Fault>
       </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

But if I try to get the details I get nothing!
I do it as follows:

```
String code = soapMsg.getSOAPBody().getFault().getFaultCode();
String faultString = soapMsg.getSOAPBody().getFault().getFaultString();
Detail detail = reply.getSOAPBody().getFault().getDetail();
if(detail == null)
   System.out.println("No detail");
else
   System.out.println("Detail value is "+detail.getNodeValue());
Iterator it = reply.getSOAPBody().getFault().getDetail().getDetailEntries();
StringBuilder details = new StringBuilder();
details.append("Detail:");
while(it.hasNext())
{
  System.out.println("Has details");
  DetailEntry temp = (DetailEntry) it.next();
  System.out.println(temp.getTextContent());
  System.out.println(temp.getValue());
  details.append(temp.getValue());
  details.append("-");
  Iterator it2 = temp.getChildElements();
  while(it2.hasNext())
  {
    Node t = (Node) it2.next();
    System.out.println("Node value:"+t.getNodeValue());
  }
}
System.out.println("Details:"+details.toString());
```

It is printed:
Detail value is **null**
Has details
Details:**null-**
Node value:**null**
Can someone help on this? Why can I not get the details of SOAP fault? It is included in the SOAP message?

UPDATE: The code and the faultstring is printed correctly.
I.e.
**code:S:Server

FaultString:java.lang.NullPointerException**

Thanks

Comment: Your example does not show if the detail element actually has any textual content in the ns2:frame element. Have you tried accessing the childnodes of DetailEntry using `getChildElements` or any of the dom methods?

Comment: @Jorn:I see what you mean. The fault detail seems to report the stack trace in the server(have updated post). Tried to use getChildElements, I get in the while loop but null value is printed. Have updated code in post as well

Answer (score 1):

The Method `getNodeValue` will always return `null` for a DOM element, `getTextContent` would be better but in your case all information is contained in attributes of nested elements. You would have to traverse these nested elements with code like the following. Please note that I haven't tested the code yet.

```
String uri = "http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/";
QName qnException = new QName(uri, "exception");
QName qnStackTrace = new QName(uri, "stackTrace");
QName qnFrame = new QName(uri, "frame");

SOAPFault fault = soapMsg.getSOAPBody().getFault();
System.out.println("code=" + fault.getFaultCode());
System.out.println("faultString=" + fault.getFaultString());

for (Iterator i=fault.getDetail().getDetailEntries(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    DetailEntry detailEntry = (DetailEntry)i.next();

    for (Iterator j=detailEntry.getChildElements(qnException); j.hasNext(); ) {
        SOAPElement exception = (SOAPElement)j.next();
        System.out.println("exception class=" + exception.getAttribute("class"));

        for (Iterator k=exception.getChildElements(qnStackTrace); k.hasNext(); ) {
            SOAPElement stackTrace = (SOAPElement)k.next();

            for (Iterator l=stackTrace.getChildElements(qnFrame); l.hasNext(); ) {
                SOAPElement frame = (SOAPElement)l.next();
                System.out.println(" class=" + frame.getAttribute("class"));
                System.out.println(" file =" + frame.getAttribute("file"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.As soon as I test it, I will let you know if it worked

Comment: its works ? or someone can help to get the source code for debug this at java 1.8 RT.jar